# When Strings mismatch , I expect NULL return instead I integer(0) is returned

Tags: r, null

In the following code when strings don't match i.e. when `"b"` is searched for in `reviews` list, I should get NULL. But I get `integer(0)`. How to force it to be null. `is.null` does not seem to work.

```
names <- c("a","b")
reviews <- c("a","d")

for (i in seq_len(length(names))) {       
  x <-which(names[i]==reviews)
  print(x)
  print(is.null(x))
  print(!is.null(x))
}
#[1] 1
#[1] FALSE
#[1] TRUE
#integer(0)
#[1] FALSE
#[1] TRUE
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any reason why not simply using this `names %in% reviews`

Comment: `which(x)` returns induces of `x` for which `x` is `TRUE`.  The vector it returns is of the length equal to the number of `TRUE`s in `x`. If there there are zero `TRUE` elements in `x`, then it returns object of length `0` suggesting no indexes.  I guess `NULL` seems like a good option too, but that's not the behavior.

Comment: @amrrs That's a great tip ! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you think it "should" return NULL? Is it documented somewhere that `which(c(FALSE,FALSE))` returns NULL? No, the help for `which` says:

```
 If ‘arr.ind == FALSE’ (the default), an integer vector with
 ‘length’ equal to ‘sum(x)’, i.e., to the number of ‘TRUE’s in ‘x’;
```

How many TRUEs are there? Zero. So what do you get back? A vector of integers of length zero -`integer(0)`. That is not the same as `NULL`.

`NULL` is generally reserved for things that are `undefined` in some sense, but it is *not* what is returned in this case.

If you want to trap this case, test against `length(z)==0`, which will be `TRUE` if `z` is a zero-length vector (of any type, it could be `character(0)` depending on your application).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Yes I wanted to trap this case with an 'if(x==0)' and was getting an error. 'if(length(x)==0)' works perfectly.